# How make a calculation table from 2 tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables and want to make a percent table.

```
select a.claim_by,
count(select count (claim_by) from itcorp_first_response a) + (select count (claim_by) from itcorp_reopen_response b) as total_response,
count(select count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) from itcorp_first_response a) + (select count (response_time > minute (response_time -30)) from itcorp_reopen_response b) as total_target,
count(select count (response_time > minute (response_time +30)) from itcorp_first_response a) + (select count (response_time > minute (response_time +30)) from itcorp_reopen_response b) as total_untarget
from itcorp_first_response a, itcorp_reopen_response b
where a.claim_by in ('Petrus Asbirianto','Ifnu Muhardhi','Riko Rachmat Saleh','Muhammad Irsan','Dion Laksmana') 
and a.claim_by = b.claim_by
GROUP BY a.claim_by;
```

but getting below error:

> QL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=78589) You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'select count (claim_by) from
>   itcorp_first_response a) + (select count (claim_by)' at line 2

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: First of all there are parentheses missing, e.g. the opening and closing parantheses here: `count((select count (claim_by) from itcorp_first_response a) + (select count (claim_by) from itcorp_reopen_response b)) as total_response,`.

Comment: Both correlated subqueries with aggregation, _and_ a GROUP BY?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. [mcve]

Comment: This looks overly complicated. And wrong. Q1: `select count (claim_by) from itcorp_first_response a` counts all non-null `claim_by` occurrences in the table `itcorp_first_response`. Q2: `select count (claim_by) from itcorp_reopen_response b` does the same for table `itcorp_reopen_response`. `select count( (Q1) + (Q2) )` counts the result only if both results are not null. This same value is then evaluated for every row in the main query. That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: It looks like there can be multiple claims per `claim_by` in the tables. Is this so? If yes, isn't there an additional claim ID to tell which claim an entry is about? Please tell us what the table's unique keys are. You can paste the `CREATE TABLE` statements here. You can even create a fiddle (e.g. in https://dbfiddle.uk/). Sample data would be helpful to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner,
here are tables describe :

itcorp_first_response
created_by varchar(128) NO   
ticket_id varchar(20) YES   
subject mediumtext YES   
claim_by varchar(128) NO   
created datetime NO   
claim_time datetime NO   
answer text NO   
response_time time YES   


itcorp_reopen_response
created_by varchar(128) NO   
ticket_id varchar(20) YES   
subject mediumtext YES   
claim_by varchar(128) NO   
reopened datetime YES   
claim_time datetime NO   
answer text NO   
response_time time YES

Comment: As it is currently, you're placing a lot of the work just to create the initial conditions on the person who would be helping you. I think you should edit your Question and insert the new information. Making it easy for people to read your Question will increase the likelihood of someone answering it.

Comment: @enggal . . . I would suggest that you ask a NEW question.  Provide sample data, desired results.  Explain the logic you want to implement for the final data.  A non-working query does not convey as much useful information as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

```
count(select count (claim_by) from itcorp_first_response a) +
     (select count (claim_by) from itcorp_reopen_response b)
   as total_response,
```

-->

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a ) +
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a ) as total_response
```

That should avoid the 1064 error.)

Don't count a count.

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(x)` unless you need to check `x` for `NULL`.

```
(response_time > minute (response_time -30))
```

What is the datatype?  (When asking questions here, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  If it is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, say something like

```
( response_time > NOW() - 30 MINUTE )
```

Then, realize that `COUNT()` checks for existence of rows; it does not tally up truth, but SUM does:

```
SELECT  count (response_time > minute (response_time -30))
            from  itcorp_reopen_response b
```

-->

```
SELECT  SUM(response_time > NOW() - 30 MINUTE)
            from  itcorp_reopen_response b
```

Please do not re-use aliases (`a`, `b`); it confuses the reader.

Make those fixes and show us what you have; there may be more to 'fix'.